# Which is better @ResponseStatus or ResponseEntity?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, controller

Which option is preferable in your opinion?

```
@PostMapping(value = "/create")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Student createStudent (@RequestBody Student student) {
    return service.createStudent(student);
}
    
@PostMapping(value = "/create")
public ResponseEntity<Student> createStudent (@RequestBody Student student) {
    return new ResponseEntity(service.createStudent(student), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

ResponseEntity provides you better flexibility.For example, Based on certain conditions you can decide on different status codes.

But with Response Status it's kind of fixed status code.